# Windows Server Clear on Logout Policy

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I was wondering is it possible to create a policy on Windows Server 2008 R2 or 2012 that will clear everything (all files from desktop, documents, etc) once the user has logged out of the system? It will basically seem like once they log back into the system it will look like a new PC.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look into this [thread](http://superuser.com/questions/244849/wiping-an-accounts-setting-and-files-when-user-logs-off).

Comment: There is also mandatory profiles, here are some links but there's also some good YouTube videos on this as well.  `1.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895(v=vs.85).aspx `2.` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/973289 `3.` http://www.jeroentielen.nl/howto-create-a-mandatory-profile-server-2012. I'd do some reading, watch some videos, and then test until you get it to work from the OS you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the user connecting to it in the local group **Guest**.

That way the system create temporary profile for those users and they are deleted at logoff.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a domain based system with roaming profiles, there are a few GPO settings which could potentially achieve this effect:

[Delete cached copies of roaming profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958989.aspx)

[Prevent Roaming Profile changes from propagating to the server](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/03/group-policy-setting-of-the-week-16-prevent-roaming-profile-changes-from-propagating-to-the-server/)

As suggested in the comments, a mandatory profile could also work. The best thing to do would be to test based on your own circumstances and requirements.